# how to make css autocompletation in .tsx/jsx file when using vscode?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I`m using vscode to develop my RN project, but when i edit it in tsx file, the css autocompletion does not work. The same in jsx file.

I have used some plugins, css in js etc, but can`t fit my need.

```
StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can configure IntelliSense provided in VS Code. You can configure it following guidelines in the link below.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript